# Hide drawer in custom drawer component in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

`SideMenu` is my custom drawer component and it has `X` button in it.

When I press the `X` button, I want the drawer to be closed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.props.navigation.closeDrawer() or this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer() for this.

```
<Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.closeDrawer()} />
```

or

```
<Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()} />
```

[Read this doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `toggleDrawer()`. Very basic example:

```
render() {
  const { navigator } = this.props

  return (
    <Button
      onPress={() => navigator.toggleDrawer({ side: 'right', animated: true })} />
  )
}
```